# UHD problem with two versions on the same host

Tags: uhd

I have installed uhd 4.4.0.0 on a raspberry pi device running ubuntu 20.04. Everything was OK until I upgraded the Ubuntu version to 22. It probably bring with it Gnu Radio and an older version of UHD - UHD_4.1.0.5-3.
I call UHD from my C++ code. It calls UHD_4.1.0.5-3 and crashes, while if I run an exe from host/build/examples it calls 4.4. and works OK.
How can I solve it? How can I get rid of the UHD_4.1.0.5-3?
Thanks

I re-installed 4.4 but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I had a similar issue the other day, had to reinstall gnu radio from source to get gnu radio to work with the right version of UHD. But there might be an easier way

Comment: I don't need GNU Radio.